# Discuss the recurrence of such a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

$\{X_n:n\ge0\}$ is a Markov chain in $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ whose transition probability satisfy $p_{01}=1, p_{i,i+1}+p_{i,i-1}=1$ and 
$$
p_{i,i+1}=(\frac{i+1}{i})^\alpha p_{i,i-1}, i\ge1,\alpha\in(0,\infty)
$$
then discuss the recurrence of the Markov chain.

Comment: Didn't you want to write:
$$p_{i,i+1}=\left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)^\alpha p_{i,i-1}, i\ge1,\alpha\in(0,\infty)$$

Comment: No. I did type the formula correctly.